# Will websocket lost data during receiving and sending?

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I am using the third-party websocket library of Python

(https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-sock)

it is ran with flask framework

I am sending over a data with 2568 length of characters, the server sometimes can receive full data, sometimes it receive only total length of 1420

The flask web application is running in server, and my data is sending from my localhost pc, i checked with wireshark, my data was successfully send over to server with 2568 length of characters, but my server sometimes receiving only 1420 length of data/string

i just contacted the developer of this third-party library, here is it https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-sock/issues/6

my question is to understanding, will websocket lost data in the middle or i am sending too much sizes of data?

**Update #1**

### Server

```
from flask_sock import Sock

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

@sock.route('/websocket/instance_state')
def instance_state(ws):
    while ws.connected:

        print("Receiving :: ")
        
        req = ws.receive()

        print(f"{len(req)}")

        ws.send(req)
```

### Client

```
import websockets
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

    while True:

        the_string = "a" * 2600
        print(f"Sending :: {the_string}")
        await websocket.send(the_string)
        resp = await websocket.recv()
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimal reproducable code example (both here and particulary on your github issue) so that anyone trying to assit with this can re-create the problem to debug it.

Comment: @v25 thanks for the mention, i had updated with the reproduce code

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, I get `2600` every time. [Client code I used](https://pastebin.com/ge4fExMx). How are you running client and server and what versions are you using.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden thanks for supporting, I cannot show you my code but the version that i use is Flask==1.1.2, flask-sock==0.3.0, and Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1

Comment: @BasvanderLinden because my data was json, so i'm not sure why it lost the data in receiving, i checked with wireshark my sending was ok, anyway, i had switched to socketio it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had overcome the situation by implementing Flask-SocketIO instead of Flask-Sock, so the issue was not solved but due to project timeline, Flask-SocketIO works fine